# How to send the data which is sent from another activity by intent?

Tags: php, android, mysql, eclipse, listview

Before listing out the items, I have a function of the app to create a new data where it includes a unique id from another activity. The unique data is "sid". I used PHP to connect to a phpmyadmin database.

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['foodName']) && isset($_POST['foodPrice']) && isset($_POST['foodType']) && isset($_POST['sid']) {

$foodName = $_POST['foodName'];
$foodPrice = $_POST['foodPrice'];
$foodType = $_POST['foodType'];
$sid = $_POST['sid'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO food(foodName, foodPrice, foodType, sid) VALUES('$foodName', '$foodPrice', '$foodType', '$sid')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Food successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

And this is the intent to receive the data from the other activity :

```
Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (sid) from intent
    sid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_SID);
```

Lastly, I have the this in the class when it is executed :

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("foodName", getFoodName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("foodPrice", getFoodPrice));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("foodType", getFoodType));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sid", sid));
```

Is there something that I did wrong somewhere? On my table I have this "sid" too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do the following
in the first Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("sid", VALUE);
startActivity(intent);
```

in second activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("sid");
}
```

Comment: If you know that you are getting a String as an extra, you can directly use `String extra = getIntent().getExtraString("sid");`

Comment: the if conditional is only extra check, sometimes you need to call an activity without adding any data with the intent.